# css/html formated text over image on mouseover

Tags: html, css

I have a working example, but I want to format the text which is shown when the image gets hovered. Here is the code:

```css
.ecommerce-categories [class^=col-] > a:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 50px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
 transition: all .7s ease;
}

.ecommerce-categories [class^=col-] > a:hover:before { 
  opacity: 1; 
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 categories">
  <a href="#"  data-text="Day for rafting and outdoor activities" style="background: url('images/catagories/cat-rafting.jpg') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;" >
```

I want to be able to edit the text inside the attribute 'data-text' with html tags. How should I refactor this code so I can do that? (data-text="Day for rafting and outdoor activities").

Thank you.

Comment: use `javascript` for that

Comment: That's not an appropriate use of `content`...it should **never** hold *actual content*

Comment: No options to do just with css/html with this code? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Per the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-content) HTML added in the CSS content attribute does not alter the document tree. So in your case you can't format a part of the text contained in `data-text`.

To do so you can make use of javascript. There is a ton of javascript tooltip plugins / libraries / code examples available on the internet.